# Bathroom nozzle part

Tags: bathroom, faucet, washer

Is there a specific name for the part of a bathroom nozzle the holds the washer? 
I have a two handles brass BR faucet with a flat wide spout that I believe need a washer which I ordered. The problem is it seems like I'm going to need a part yo hold it. When I feel the inside of the water outlet, it feels like it's missing something.
I can use all of the help I can get in more ways than one! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

## Aerator Assembly

[image]

([source](http://8-ball.xyz/737907a46eba7e54-bathroom-faucet-aerator-assembly.html))

---

They're all pretty standard. You should be able to find one at your local hardware store. Or, buy a [faucet aerator assembly](https://www.google.com/search?q=aerator%20assembly&biw=1024&bih=639&tbm=shop&source=lnms&sa=X&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0ahUKEwiHjq3_3orMAhWBKCYKHQyvCT8Q_AUICygB&dpr=1#tbm=shop&q=faucet%20aerator%20assembly) on Google.